# default(struct) - Good Style?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

Well it's not really a singleton, but I don't know if there is a pattern for something so rare.

For example, there is no way in the framework to get a `IWin32Window` representing the console of a console app.

```
public struct ConsoleWindow : IWin32Window
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    IntPtr IWin32Window.Handle
    {
        get { return GetConsoleWindow(); }
    }
}
```

And then you use it like this.

```
MessageBox.Show(default(ConsoleWindow), "Hello, World!");
```

Am I being too clever for my own good? Is this the ".net way"?

I considered using a static readonly field (called what?), or just `new ConsoleWindow()` but neither seemed right.

(Obviously performance isn't an issue in this case as Handle is accessed exactly once.)

Comment: What is it that you are trying to solve? Are you asking if it is ok to return GetConsoleWindow from a struct? As it stands, your struct isn't a singleton

Comment: Is default(struct) too much voodoo?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a class with a private constructor and a single instance property.

```
public class ConsoleWindow : IWin32Window
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    IntPtr IWin32Window.Handle
    {
       get { return GetConsoleWindow(); }
    }

    private ConsoleWindow(){}

    public static ConsoleWindow Instance
    { 
        get 
        { 
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new ConsoleWindow();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    private static ConsoleWindow _instance = null;
}

MessageBox.Show(ConsoleWindow.Instance, "Hello, World!");
```

I believe this is the standard singleton pattern used when creating a static class is not possible.

Comment: Indeed. This a quite a bit more code for no benefit though, isn't it?

Comment: It's not a benefit in this particular case, no. The reason to use this instead of your struct is mainly because this pattern works in more cases. 

By using a more standardized pattern, other programmers will understand better what you are doing.